# How to solve this KeyError:0 in JupyterLab?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, google-colaboratory, jupyter-lab

I run this code in Google Colab, it works well. But when I run it in my JupyterLab, this keyerror:0 happens. How can I solve this problem?

```
import sys
import sklearn
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mpl.rc('axes', labelsize=14)
mpl.rc('xtick', labelsize=12)
mpl.rc('ytick', labelsize=12)

# Where to save the figures
PROJECT_ROOT_DIR = "."
CHAPTER_ID = "classification"
IMAGES_PATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT_DIR, "images", CHAPTER_ID)
os.makedirs(IMAGES_PATH, exist_ok=True)

def save_fig(fig_id, tight_layout=True, fig_extension="png", resolution=300):
    path = os.path.join(IMAGES_PATH, fig_id + "." + fig_extension)
    print("Saving figure", fig_id)
    if tight_layout:
        plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig(path, format=fig_extension, dpi=resolution)

from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version=1)
X, y = mnist["data"], mnist["target"]

%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

some_digit = X[0]
some_digit_image = some_digit.reshape(28, 28)
plt.imshow(some_digit_image, cmap=mpl.cm.binary)
plt.axis("off")

save_fig("some_digit_plot")
plt.show()
```

[This is the KeyError:0 shown in the JupyterLab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0nYM.png)

Comment: Please do not post images of data/code/error messages. Post the text directly here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

According to the given screenshot, it is actually a pandas key error for `X`, but there is no pandas reference to the `X` in the given code, which it means that somehow `X` value was corrupted by mistake.

Hence I recommend you to restart your jupyter kernel and try it again.

**Note**: According to your code `type(X[0])` will be `numpy.ndarray`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I test the type of X and found it is DataFrame, now the problem has been solved by transferring it to array.